# Exercice 3 section 1.5-( Do Carmo's diiferential geometrry)

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

my question comes from  Exercice$ 3 $ section$ 1.5$ ( Do Carmo's diiferential geometrry)

Assume that $\alpha(I)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ ($\alpha$ is a planar curve ) and $k$ is the signed curvature
prove that :

1- The indicatrix of tangents is a regular parametrized curve.

2- prove that $\frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{d\theta}{ds} n$ that is, $k=\frac{d\theta}{ds}$

where t(s) is the tangent of the curve alpha and $\theta(s)$  be the angle from $e_1$ to$ t (s)$ in the orientation of $\mathbb{R}^2$

the problem is that let's consider $\alpha $ the parametrisation of a stright line so alpha is an affine function , $t(s)$ will be a constant so the derivative of the The indicatrix of tangents will be zero and this contradict what we want to prove in this exercice

for the second question it is clear that $t(s)=(\cos(\theta(s),\sin(\theta(s)))$ ....

Comment: Read the rules at the beginning of the exercise set. DoCarmo says explicitly that $k\ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin , you are right . but another question comes if the trace of  curve conatins a segment, we can parametrise this curve by using the usual parametrisation by  The indicatrix of tangents and this curve will be a regular ?

Comment: No, the tangent indicatrix is regular if and only if $k\ne 0$.